# Liquibase fails to execute sql statement which works as SQL script in Oracle

Tags: oracle, liquibase

Liquibase fails to execute:

```
<sql dbms="oracle"
             endDelimiter="/"
             relativeToChangelogFile="true"
             splitStatements="true"
             stripComments="false">INSERT INTO SYSTEM_MESSAGE (CODE, SYST_MESS_TYPE_DOVA_CODE, IS_NATIVE, SYS_VERSION, SYS_DELETE_STATUS, SYS_MODIFY_UID) VALUES ('mi.board', 'MENU_ITEM', 'N', 0, 'N', 'admin')</sql>
```

With root exception:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (DB.PKH_SYSTEM_MESSAGE) violated
```

The constraint checks if there are no duplicates with same CODE and SYS_VERSION.
But the table that has the constraint DB.PKH_SYSTEM_MESSAGE is empty.
This statement however works when ran as a script directly in the database.

What could be the issue here?

The same applies to when running it as xml **insert** statement

edit:

The table SYSTEM_MESSAGE has a trigger which inserts the data to another table:

```
    TRIGGER "DB"."THI_SYSTEM_MESSAGE"   BEFORE INSERT ON SYSTEM_MESSAGE FOR EACH ROW DECLARE
   cuser varchar2(127); client_id varchar2(30); 
BEGIN 
 SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER'), SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CLIENT_IDENTIFIER') INTO cuser, client_id FROM DUAL; 
 IF CLIENT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN :new.sys_modify_uid := client_id; END IF; 
 IF :new.sys_version IS NULL THEN :new.sys_version := 0; END IF; 
 :new.sys_modify_time := systimestamp; 
 INSERT INTO SYSTEM_MESSAGE_H (sys_version,CODE,SYST_MESS_TYPE_DOVA_CODE,DESCRIPTION,END_DATE,IS_NATIVE,SYS_MODIFY_SID,SYS_DELETE_STATUS,sys_start_time, sys_modify_uid, sys_modify_db_user) 
 SELECT :new.sys_version,:new.CODE,:new.SYST_MESS_TYPE_DOVA_CODE,:new.DESCRIPTION,:new.END_DATE,:new.IS_NATIVE,:new.SYS_MODIFY_SID,:new.SYS_DELETE_STATUS, :new.sys_modify_time, :new.sys_modify_uid, cuser FROM dual; 
END;
```

This table is called SYSTEM_MESSAGE_H and has the constraint that is being violated

Comment: Is the query being run twice? Is the query being inserted into the correct schema/user (or are you looking at a different schema when you run the query directly)? You are trying to insert into `SYSTEM_MESSAGE` but you say `DB.PKH_SYSTEM_MESSAGE` is empty .... those tables have different names (and may be in different schemas).

Comment: @MT0 I have updated the answer. The query is being run only once.

Comment: @MT0 I am always using the same schema, when inserting trough script and when inserting with liquibase.